# Sharing image failed via intents

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am trying to share an image using intents. Please find the function for the same.

```
        if(view.getId()==R.id.sendImage){
        Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.watchyalist/mipmap/"+R.mipmap.test);
        intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgUri);
        intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Please find the image");
        chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose the app");
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

Here test is the image that I am referring to,it sends bin file when shared via whatsapp. I tried using ic_launcher, then it says failed sharing. Here is a snap shot of my manifest file

```
 android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I am unable to understand it. I tried changing the manifest tag to drawable and accordingly keeping the imag in drawable and making changes accordingly still no luck. I have kept image in the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder in project,and also tried changing the location but no use.Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRA_STREAM` is [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_STREAM) to take a `Uri` with a `content:` scheme. `android.resource:` is not `content:`. There is no requirement for any app to know how to handle your `Uri` when they receive it from your app. Plus, your `Uri` ends in a semi-random number (whatever `R.mipmap.test` happens to be for this build).

Please copy the image to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use for `EXTRA_STREAM`.